# Require() function is not working properly in below code

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

Deployed this contract on Remix IDE on InjectedWeb3 environment on Rinkeyby test network.

I tried removing the error msg statement in require, then it is not throwing error but still not working properly i.e the function is getting executed irrespective of any require condition.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;
contract RegisterLand{

struct land{
     uint area;
     string location;
     uint floorsAllowed;
     mapping(uint => address) owner;
     uint count;
     bool idExists;
}
 mapping(uint => land) lands;
 function Register(uint id,uint area, string memory location, uint 
 floorsAllowed) public
 {
    require(
            !lands[id].idExists,
            "ID already exists"
             );
  lands[id] = land(area, location, floorsAllowed,0,true);
  lands[id].owner[lands[id].count] = msg.sender;
 }
 function ViewLand(uint id) public view returns(address currentOwner, 
 uint 
 landArea, string memory landLocation, uint landFloors )
 {
  require(lands[id].idExists,
         "Id doesn't exist.");
  currentOwner = lands[id].owner[lands[id].count];
  landArea = lands[id].area;
  landLocation = lands[id].location;
  landFloors = lands[id].floorsAllowed;
 } 
}
```

error:

> Failed to decode output: Error: overflow (operation="setValue",
>   fault="overflow", details="Number can only safely store up to 53
>   bits", version=4.0.32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue that require in view/pure functions don’t revert on public networks:
https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/require-in-view-pure-functions-dont-revert-on-public-networks/1211

If you use Remix JavaScript VM then calling `ViewLand` with a non-existent `id` reverts as expected.

If you have questions on dapp development you can also ask in the OpenZeppelin Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin

Comment: Thanks. Is there any alternative that I may use here?

Comment: Your dapp needs to work around this issue unfortunately.